# iOS push notification didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError

Tags: ios, push-notification, push

I am getting following error in `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` method?

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x176e8120 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}

2015-04-16 16:18:15.760 FSE[1933:496004] ERROR Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo=0x176e8120 {NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}.
```

If anyone can help?

Comment: had you check your certificate using command in terminal....is it working properly????

Answer (score 4):

The error indicates you are using a signing certificate without the permission for push notifications set.
First enable the push notification and then create a new provisioning profile.